# dictionary problem in python with index error

Tags: python

I am writing the program to get two dictionaries, dict1 with names as keys and the number of wins as values, dict 2 with years as keys and the number of times won as values. My question is when I try to get the current year inside the for loop which need for the dict 1, it's always giving me and "index error: list index out of range"
and the problem is here as it shows "year_team[year]=winners[year-1903]".

```
def main():
    dfile=open('worldserieswinners.txt','r')
    winners=dfile.read().splitlines()

    team_wins={}
    year_team={}

    for team in winners:
        if team not in team_wins:
            team_wins[team]=1
        else:
            team_wins[team]+=1

    for year in range(1903, 2010):
        if year != 1904 and year != 1994:
            year_team[year]=winners[year-1903]

    year=int(input('Enter a year between 1903 and 2009 or 0 to quit: '))
    while year!= 0:
        if year == 1904 or year == 1994:
            print('Not played in this year')
        elif 1903>year or year>2009:
            print('Invalid choice')
        else:
            team=year_team[year]
            wins=team_wins[team]
            print('The winning team in',year,'was the',team)
            print('The',team,'won',wins,'times between 1903 and 2009.')
            year= int(input('Enter a year between 1903 and 2009 or 0 to quit: '))

    dfile.close()

main()
```

Comment: Share the sample content from the file worldserieswinners.txt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Presumably your `'worldserieswinners.txt'` file has less than 107 (2010 − 1903) lines, so that the index `year-1903` gets out of range.

Comment: Thanx alot for explaining me.  After adding some more contents to the file it worked.